# Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

> *Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed.*

Me esta saliendo este error en la consola al hacer una petición get y he estado comprobando todo el código y no se que puede ser lo que me ha provocado el fallo, porque es un array y me coge además los datos del back como se puede ver aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Code } from '../../model/code';
import { codeService } from '../../_services/codeService';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-code',
  templateUrl: './code.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./code.component.css']
})
export class CodeComponent {
  codes: any[]=[];
  idProject: number;
  
  constructor(private codeService: codeService, private router:Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.getCodes();
  }
  private getCodes(){
    this.codeService.getAll().subscribe((dato) => {
      this.codes = dato;
      console.log(dato)
      if(this.codes.length == 0){
        Swal.fire({
          title: 'No existen codes ',
          text: 'Crea un code para que aparezca en la pantalla',
          icon: 'info'
        });
      }
    });
  }
  eliminarCode(idCode:number){
    this.codeService.delete(idCode).subscribe(() =>{
      this.getCodes();
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Code eliminado correctamente',
        icon: 'success'
      });
    });
  }
  navegarCrearCode(){
    this.router.navigate(['code/']);
  }
  navegarEditarCode(idCode:number){
    this.router.navigate(['code/', this.idProject,idCode]);
  }
}
```

la clase con las propiedades:

```
export class Code {
    id: number;
    paquete: string;
    file: string;
}
```

El servicio:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { Code } from '../model/code';
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/code';
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class codeService{
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
getAll():Observable<Code[]> {
    return this.http.get<Code[]>(`${baseUrl}`).pipe(
        tap(res => console.log(res)) 
        );
}

get(id: any): Observable<Code> {
return this.http.get<Code>(`${baseUrl}/${id}`);
}
create(data: any): Observable<any> {
return this.http.post(baseUrl, data);
}
update(id: any, data: any): Observable<any> {
return this.http.put(`${baseUrl}/${id}`, data);
}
delete(id: any): Observable<any> {
return this.http.delete(`${baseUrl}/${id}`);
}
deleteAll(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.delete(baseUrl);
}
}
```

Mi html:

```html
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-center">Lista de Codes </h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="color: blue;font-weight: bolder;">Id</th>
                        <th style="color: green; font-weight: lighter;">Paquete</th>
                        <th style="color: green; font-weight: lighter;">File</th>
                        <th style="color: green; font-weight: lighter;">Operaciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   
                    <tr *ngFor="let code of codes">
                        <td>{{code.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{code.paquete}}</td>
                        <td>{{code.file}}</td>

                        <th>
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" value="Editar" (click)="navegarEditarCode(code.id)">
                                <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Eliminar" (click)="eliminarCode(code.id)">
                            </div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                
                    <div *ngIf="!codes || codes.length === 0">
                        No hay datos para mostrar.
                      </div>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a class="btn btn-success" type="submit" (click)="navegarCrearCode()">Crear Code</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" routerLink="/home">Volver</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

El error parece que esta en la forma en la que recibes y usas los datos, porque no recibes un arreglo de `Code`, recibes la respuesta completa y a partir de eso tienes que obtener los resultados que quieres. En este caso se aprecia la ventaja de usar interfaces aunque cueste un poco más de tiempo hacerlas, ya que al momento de usar los datos fuera del servicio el mismo editor te va a sugerir las opciones para autocompletar.

Tuve que empezar por recrear completamente tu respuesta `JSON`, empecemos con eso (recorte algunos objetos para no hacerlo tan largo):

**JSON**

```
{
  "data": {
    "totalPaginas": 1,
    "totalElementos": 1,
    "numPagina": 0,
    "medidaPagina": 0,
    "ultima": true,
    "contenido": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "paquete": "paquete/paquete6",
        "file": ".xsd",
        "project": null
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "paquete": "pepe/pepe",
        "file": "zip",
        "project": {
          "id": 1,
          "description": "hola buenas talde",
          "languaje": "Españo",
          "open": true,
          "users": [],
          "tags": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Como ves acá recibes `data`, y adentro es donde esta el contenido, checa con Postman que es lo que te regresa tu petición `get` y le cambias el nombre.

Después use [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) para poder hacer los requests. Basándonos en el `JSON`, saque las interfaces ([Quicktype](https://quicktype.io/)):

**Interface**

```
export interface Resultado {
  data: Data;
}

export interface Data {
  totalPaginas: number;
  totalElementos: number;
  numPagina: number;
  medidaPagina: number;
  ultima: boolean;
  contenido: Contenido[];
}

export interface Contenido {
  id: number;
  paquete: string;
  file: string;
  project?: Project;
}

export interface Project {
  id: number;
  description: string;
  languaje: string;
  open: boolean;
  users: any[];
  tags: any[];
}
```

Teniendo ya todo esto, vamos con el servicio y componente:

**Servicio**

```
export class CodeService {
  url = 'http://localhost:3000';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAll(): Observable<Data> {
    return this.http.get<Data>(`${this.url}/data`);
  }
}
```

**Componente**

```
export class CodesComponent implements OnInit {
  codes: Contenido[] = [];

  constructor(private codeService: CodeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.codeService.getAll().subscribe({
      next: (data: Data) => {
        this.codes = data.contenido;
      },
      error: (err) => {
        this.codes = [];
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Tanto en el servicio como en el componente puedes extraer los datos, pero ya es tu preferencia y que es lo que vayas a usar más veces, si solamente te interesa el `contenido` pues lo puedes modificar para que el servicio te regrese solamente eso. Por último y como extra, la línea donde checas si `this.codes` tiene una longitud mayor a 0

```
if(this.codes.length == 0)
```

la puedes cambiar simplemente por

```
if(!this.codes)
```

**Resultado**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error esta en el getAll, o eso creo lo de ponerlo en interfaz tambien lo pensé deberia de probarlo, ves algo raro en el getAll? Muchisimas gracias por responder y trataré de cambiar eso, en cuanto a los any tratare de cambiar el id y ponerlo en number y el data no se de que tipo ponerlo.

Comment: No lo había visto , pues parece que aún así lo que regresa es un arreglo de objetos, por eso te dice `[object Object]`,  y cuando intentas acceder a él como `code.id` y otros es donde marca el error. Déjame editar el código.  Igual si pudieras compartir el JSON completo para ver qué es lo que recibes sería más fácil.

Comment: Ya edite el código.

Comment: He realizado los diferentes cambios que estuvimos viendo y no se solucionó nada, cambié el tipado y el método de getAll pero no consigo que se vaya ese error

Comment: Comparte tu JSON para replicar la petición.

Comment: {"contenido":[{"id":7,"paquete":"paquete/paquete6","file":".xsd","project":null},{"id":6,"paquete":"paquete/paquete5","file":".xsd","project":null},{"id":5,"paquete":"paquete/paquete4","file":".xml","project":null},{"id":4,"paquete":"paquete/paquete3","file":".xml","project":null},{"id":3,"paquete":"paquete/paquete2","file":".xml","project":null},{"id":2,"paquete":"paquete/paquete1","file":".xml","project":null},{"id":1,"paquete":"pepe/pepe","file":"zip","project":{"id":1,"description":"hola buenas talde","languaje":"Españo","open":true,"users":[],"tags":[]}}]

Comment: El error es ese, que esa no es tu respuesta `JSON` cuando quieres obtener todos. ya actualice el código.